# Datagrid Row Details - Can I replace the row with a custom component

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there a way to use clrDgReplace with a custom component for the row details?

I know you can use it like this

`<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded [clrDgReplace]="true">
        Lorem ipsum...
    </clr-dg-row-detail>`

but can you get the same functionality when invoking row details in this manner?

`<my-detail *clrIfExpanded [user]="user" ngProjectAs="clr-dg-row-detail"></my-detail>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `<clr-dg-row-detail>` element inside of `my-detail`'s template: https://plnkr.co/edit/kPbucjmAKXXwayMm1jmw?p=preview